# How to apply same set of changes to different repos using git?

Tags: git

I have different repositories that are all ultimately copied from one repo. But these repos don't contain the commit history of one another.

i.e.,

- I have a project in repo X
- I copy the files from X without the commit history to another repo Y and made some customization there.
- Similarly, I have L, M, N repos.
- All of these repos Y, L, M, N have different commits on top of the files from X
- Now I made some changes to X that can be applied to Y, L, M, N without much conflicts (Like a new feature)

The question is How do I go about applying those changes to Y, L, M, N?

Do I need to manually repeat all of the changes on all repos or is there a better way?

Comment: Git does not involve “changes”.

Comment: you might be interested in learning about [git patches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch).

Comment: @DaemonPainter I Think that is what I am looking. But the manual is too much for the current me. Is there any guides on its usage that I can refer?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `git format-patch` in the X project to create a patch file(s). There are many flags there, but in the simple usecase, you usually care about two of them - `-n` specifies how many commits from the HEAD will be stored in patch files, and `-o` specifies the target directory for them. E.g.:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/x (master)
$ git format-patch -n1 -o /tmp
/tmp/0001-some-commit.patch
```

Then, you can use `git am` in the other project(s) to apply those patches. If they apply cleanly, you'll just get another commit in the project. If there are conflicts, you'll have to resolve them:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git/y (master)
$ git am /tmp/0001-some-commit.patch
Applying: Some commit
```

Comment: will this work with different repo? I tried this, but when checking the status using `git apply --check file.patch` they all fail. Don't know how can I get more information on the error though. `git am` fails silently

Comment: Typically I would assume it to leave conflict markers rather than failing but that is not the case I assume.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of struggle I have managed to work it out. For future reference for any body having the same issue I am posting my solution here

first create the patch (thanks to Mureinik's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311883/how-to-apply-same-set-of-changes-to-different-repos-using-git/#answer-66312630))

```
git format-patch --ignore-space-change -1 <cimmit_hash>
```

then apply the patch using the unix `patch` utility instead of `git am`

```
 patch -p1 --binary --merge -l < ../path/to/your/patch/file
```

This will get you to a point where you can manage manually.